# How to list git log for given directory

Tags: git

I would like to display git log from my current directory, while repo is located in different directory.

For example I have git repository in /tmp/fake_git/

```
:~$ cd /tmp/fake_git/
:/tmp/fake_git$ git log
commit edb15e07c007237c8c06fefbb5ffd8168f4ee3d7
[...] And so on it works
```

But when I try to do it from other directory it doesn't

```
:~$ cd /
:/$ git log /tmp/fake_git/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
:/$ git log -- /tmp/fake_git/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `-C` argument to call git as if it was called from a different location.

```
git -C /tmp/fake_git/ log
```

From `git(1)`:

> ```
>   -C <path>
>        Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working
>        directory. When multiple -C options are given, each subsequent
>        non-absolute -C <path> is interpreted relative to the preceding -C
>        <path>.
>
>       This option affects options that expect path name like --git-dir and
>        --work-tree in that their interpretations of the path names would be
>        made relative to the working directory caused by the -C option. For
>        example the following invocations are equivalent:
>
>           git --git-dir=a.git --work-tree=b -C c status
>            git --git-dir=c/a.git --work-tree=c/b status
> ```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for quick response. That works fine and I can add some more argument like:
`git -C /tmp/fake_git/.git/ log --numstat`